# Generate CSS from ARRAY

Tags: php, arrays

I want to know how to parse the following array and generate it to CSS, here are the array :

```
$css = array(
        '.item-image|text-align' => 'center',
        '.item-image|vertical-align' => 'middle',
        '.item-image img.single_image|width' => '300px'
    );
```

With array above, I need to get the result like this :

```
.item-image {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.item-image img.single_image {
    width: 300px;
}
```

As you can see, between the CSS class and the CSS properties are separated by **|** , and also the 1st and 2nd array are has the same key, so it should merge  the **text-align** and **vertical-align** in the same markup (in **.item-image** class ).

Thanks and I really appreciate for any helps :)

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, include it in the question. If not, do it! It's far more rewarding (and you'll learn much more) to try things by yourself. Getting it wrong first won't do any harm :).

Comment: @ishegg : thanks, I'll try too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on it.
Make a new array of it and walk through it and output the keys and values.
The new array will be a more "simple multidimensional array".

```
$css = array(
    '.item-image|text-align' => 'center',
    '.item-image|vertical-align' => 'middle',
    '.item-image img.single_image|width' => '300px'
);

$new = array();

Foreach($css as $key => $val){
    $parts = explode("|", $key);
    If(!isset($new[$parts[0]])) $new[$parts[0]] = array();

    $new[$parts[0]][$parts[1]] = $val;
}

//Var_dump($new);

Foreach($new as $key => $subarray){
    Echo $key ."{\n";
    Foreach($subarray as $key2 => $val){
        Echo $key2 . ": " .$val .";\n";
    }
    Echo "}\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/niLPi

Comment: You’re missing the semi colons at the end of each property.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide you small hint to fix your problem .I dont say its a best way to do it .But it might help you

```
<?php
$css = array(
        '.item-image|text-align' => 'center',
        '.item-image|vertical-align' => 'middle',
        '.item-image img.single_image|width' => '300px'
    );

    foreach($css  as $key=>$val){

        $response=explode('|',$key);

        echo $response[0].' {'.$response[1].':'.$val.'}';

    }
```

output will be

```
.item-image {text-align:center}
.item-image {vertical-align:middle}
.item-image img.single_image {width:300px}
```

Its not done completely still you have to check if key is already exist then you have to update your css proeprty suppose you may have `.item-image` have multiple time in array

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this: using a `for`, a `foreach`, `while` or array function, and it might grow to include multidimensionals arrays or much more stuff.

You already have a `for` and `foreach` answer on previous answers and with `while` would be pretty much the same.

So I'll give you a more advanced solution using `array_walk`

```
$css = array(
    '.item-image|text-align' => 'center',
    '.item-image|vertical-align' => 'middle',
    '.item-image img.single_image|width' => '300px'
);
$cssFinal = '';
array_walk($css, function($value, $key) use (&$cssFinal) {
    $key = explode('|', $key);
    $cssFinal .= array_key_exists(0, $key) && array_key_exists(1, $key) ? $key[0].'{'.$key[1].':'.$value.';};'."\r\n" : ''; 
});
file_put_contents('your.css', $cssFinal);
```

Notice we validate if the key exist for 0 and 1, otherwise it shows nothing.

and we add a break line at the end of the string both for file and for browser, of course if you want it written to a file

It will write a file with your css in it:

```
.item-image{text-align:center;};
.item-image{vertical-align:middle;};
.item-image img.single_image{width:300px;};
```